# Apache FilesMatch directive to match requested domain

Tags: apache, url, configuration

I'm trying to setup the FilesMatch directive in such a way that when the user requests a resource that matches the domain name, only then will the resource be served.

For example:

`example.com/example.com.html` = good

`example.com/other.com.html` = not allowed, serves `error.html` instead

I'm currently considering configuring Apache like so:

```
<FilesMatch regexp+domain_name+regexp>
    allow the resource...
</FilesMatch>
```

But to achieve this effect I would need to have the domain of the request as a variable somehow.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This option doesn't only check if the file exists, but also if it matches your desired pattern:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^%{SERVER_NAME}\.html$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

There are more ways to do it, but rewriting gives you the most and probably also the most powerful options. It does require `mod_rewrite` to be activated though.

Comment: You 'unaccepted' my answer?! That is kinda surprising...Can you give some feedback where it went wrong, so I can fix it?