# Apache - allowing resources if they contain domain name inside the file name

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I'm faced with this rather odd conundrum.

I need to be able to allow resources to the user based on whether or not they contain the domain name within the requested file name.

**Resource format:**

```
unique_id + _ + domain_name + file_extension
```

Example:

```
503_example.com.html
```

**Scenario:**

User enters this URL:

```
http://example.com/503_example.com.html
```

He should be served the requested resource because the domain names match.

Another user requests:

```
http://example.com/503_mysite.com.html
```

He should be served `denied.html` instead because the domain names don't match.

How would I achieve this effect with `mod_rewrite` or any other apache directive?

Also note that the domain names will vary, so I couldn't use a literal name like `example.com`.

Comment: That's funny, the exact same question has been posted 2 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267407/regexp-that-ignores-everything-after-a-question-mark-symbol/43267817 Are you guys working on the same project? :-)

Comment: Sort of, he wanted to post another question but related to apache specifically not just regular expressions. But can't post second question yet. I think they are different enough but share the same objective.

Comment: So you decided to repost your question? Un-cheking my solution yesterday and posting it again today....that seems kinda odd to me oO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256834/apache-filesmatch-directive-to-match-requested-domain

Comment: Btw, I asked for feedback why you unchecked it, after it was already checked. Wanted to know where it went wrong...no answer...